# Using Raspberry Pi Display on CM3 with Android Things

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, android-things

I'm developing an app on Raspberry Pi 3 using Android Things as OS. I started using the normal Raspberry Pi 3 with the official touch screen. Everything worked fine, so I tried the same setup on the development board with the rpi compute module 3 lite (CM3L). Unfortunately the display doesn't turn on.

After some research I found this: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/cmio-display.md

Seems like I have to adjust the options for SDA and SLC on the OS as well as changing the device tree. But as I am using Android Things as OS, I don't know if this is even possible. Is there a way to use the adb cli for configs like this?

Answer (score 0):

[CM3/CM3L](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/README.md) is not in Android Things [Supported Hardware Platforms](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/), so seems it's impossible to configure official Raspberry DSI touch screen properly on OS level. But, if Android Things really works on CM3, you can use display with non DSI interface, e.g., HDMI like [this](https://www.waveshare.com/4inch-hdmi-lcd.htm) with [User Space Driver](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/drivers/input) for touch like [that](https://github.com/dirkvranckaert/touchinputdisplaydriver).