# Android Things Image on CM3

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver, android-things, device-tree

I am trying to get a Android Things Image to boot on the Compute Module 3.

I have gone through several trial and error to try and get a working image. Currently I sit in the Kernel after getting through the DTB problem I was originally facing.

I use dd to flash the image through RPIBOOT, I validate the pi fully works with Raspian.

This is what I see in the serial console:

```
    MMC:   mmc@7e300000: 0
    reading uboot.env
    In:    serial
    Out:   serial
    Err:   serial
    Net:   Net Initialization Skipped
    No ethernet found.
    ANDROID: Attempting slot b, tries remaining 6
    ANDROID: Booting slot: b
    Failed to mount ext2 filesystem...
    ** Unrecognized filesystem type **
    libfdt fdt_check_header(): FDT_ERR_BADMAGIC
    ANDROID: reboot reason: "(none)"
    ** Invalid Android Image header **
    Android boot failed, error -1.
    resetting ...
    U-�MMC:   mmc@7e300000: 0
    reading uboot.env
    In:    serial
    Out:   serial
    Err:   serial
    Net:   Net Initialization Skipped
    No ethernet found.
    ANDROID: Attempting slot a, tries remaining 5
    ANDROID: Booting slot: a
    72 bytes read in 31 ms (2 KiB/s)
    ANDROID: reboot reason: "(none)"
    Booting kernel at 0x1000000 with fdt at 2efe8600...


    ## Booting Android Image at 0x01000000 ...
    Kernel load addr 0x01000800 size 8385 KiB
    Kernel command line: buildvariant=userdebug
    RAM disk load addr 0x11000000 size 4947 KiB
    ## Flattened Device Tree blob at 2efe8600
       Booting using the fdt blob at 0x2efe8600
       XIP Kernel Image ... OK
       Loading Ramdisk to 2cb2b000, end 2cfffb11 ... OK
       reserving fdt memory region: addr=0 size=1000
       reserving fdt memory region: addr=2efe8600 size=ba00
       Loading Device Tree to 2dff1000, end 2dfff9ff ... OK

    Starting kernel ...
```

Note The file system can't be mounted:

```
ANDROID: Attempting slot b, tries remaining 6
ANDROID: Booting slot: b
Failed to mount ext2 filesystem...
```

It will sit there forever.  I have a feeling it is still something is wrongs with the Device Tree Blob that got me here. I also know the image is okay because I can boot it on a PI 3 B

I have tried both a CM3L and CM.

Both do the same thing and respond the same to the changes so I'm fairly confident that it is not a eMMC vs SD issue.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I could debug this? Or even better a resource I can utilize to find the Android Things Kernel code for PI?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50210665/using-raspberry-pi-display-on-cm3-with-android-things

Comment: I am aware it isn't officially supported. I am trying to support it myself.